# Limitar texto a ser selecionado do input com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para limitar o valor a ser selecionado com JavaScript.

Por exemplo, eu quero pegar apenas o indicador de país do número digitado, mas é diferente a quantidade de caracteres para cada país, tipo, o Brasil tem 3 "+55", já os Estados Unidos tem apenas 2 "+1".

Como faço para fazer com que o JS selecione apenas esse indicador a partir desse código que seleciona o valor da input:

> $(this).val();

Lembrando que logo após o indicador de país virá um "(", por exemplo, "+99(99)99999-9999".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a regex abaixo com `.match()` você consegue pegar o código:

```
\+\d{1,3}
```

O padrão irá capturar o `+` seguido de 1 a 3 números.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("input").on("focus", function(){
   
   var ddi = $(this).val().match(/\+\d{1,3}/)[0];
   console.log(ddi);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique num input abaixo:
<br>
<input type="text" readonly value="+9(99)99999-9999">
<br>
<input type="text" readonly value="+99(99)99999-9999">
<br>
<input type="text" readonly value="+999(99)99999-9999">
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui estou usando a função substring que retornará todo o conteudo na string que houver antes do caractere "(", ou seja, da posição 0 até onde houver o caractere que desejo limitar.

```
let numeroTelefone = '+55(31)90000-5000';
let codigoPais;
codigoPais = numeroTelefone.substring(0, numeroTelefone.indexOf("("));
```

Nesse caso, será retornado somente a string "+55".